# Instagram: Not getting updated time

Tags: jquery, instagram, instagram-api

I am using instagram api and i am using below api:-

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

The output of instagram is as below:-

```
{
    "data": [{
        "type": "image",
        "users_in_photo": [],
        "filter": "Earlybird",
        "tags": ["snow"],
        "comments": {
            "data": [{
                "created_time": "1296703540",
                "text": "Snow",
                "from": {
                    "username": "emohatch",
                    "username": "Dave",
                    "id": "1242695"
                },
                "id": "26589964"
            },
            {
                "created_time": "1296707889",
                "text": "#snow",
                "from": {
                    "username": "emohatch",
                    "username": "Emo Hatch",
                    "id": "1242695"
                },
                "id": "26609649"
            }],
            "count": 3
        }
        "caption": {
            "created_time": "1296703540",
            "text": "#Snow",
            "from": {
                "username": "emohatch",
                "id": "1242695"
            },
            "id": "26589964"
        },
        "likes": {
            "count": 1,
            "data": [{
                "username": "mikeyk",
                "full_name": "Mike Krieger",
                "id": "4",
                "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1242695_75sq_1293915800.jpg"
            }]
        },        
        "link": "http://instagr.am/p/BWl6P/",
        "user": {
            "username": "emohatch",
            "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1242695_75sq_1293915800.jpg",
            "id": "1242695",
            "full_name": "Dave"
        },
        "created_time": "1296703536",
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/f9443f3443484c40b4792fa7c76214d5_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/f9443f3443484c40b4792fa7c76214d5_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/f9443f3443484c40b4792fa7c76214d5_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "id": "22699663",
        "location": null
    },
    {
        "type": "video",
        "videos": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_102.mp4",
                "width": 480,
                "height": 480
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_101.mp4",
                "width": 640,
                "height": 640
            },
        "users_in_photo": null,
        "filter": "Vesper",
        "tags": ["snow"],
        "comments": {
            "data": [{
                "created_time": "1279332030",
                "text": "Love the sign here",
                "from": {
                    "username": "mikeyk",
                    "full_name": "Mikey Krieger",
                    "id": "4",
                    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1242695_75sq_1293915800.jpg"
                },
                "id": "8"
            },
            {
                "created_time": "1279341004",
                "text": "Chilako taco",
                "from": {
                    "username": "kevin",
                    "full_name": "Kevin S",
                    "id": "3",
                    "profile_picture": "..."
                },
                "id": "3"
            }],
            "count": 2
        },
        "caption": null,
        "likes": {
            "count": 1,
            "data": [{
                "username": "mikeyk",
                "full_name": "Mikeyk",
                "id": "4",
                "profile_picture": "..."
            }]
        },
        "link": "http://instagr.am/p/D/",
        "user": {
            "username": "kevin",
            "full_name": "Kevin S",
            "profile_picture": "...",
            "id": "3"
        },
        **"created_time"**: "1279340983",
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "id": "3",
        "location": null
    },
    ...]
}
```

If i am editing any post, then they are providing created_time. But how can i get updated_time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to get a media objects updated date/time. Even if you use the endpoint for retrieving the details for a single media object, it only contains created time.

The endpoint you are using will give you old media objects if the tag you are searching for has been recently added to it.

Comment: But, Instagram gives edited post in recent media API. But, they are not providing edited time